# Dozer Critical CVE-2014-9515 Dozer 5.5.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

Iam having one open vulnerability wen i scan my dependencies in blackduck for dozer version with 5.5.1. I tried to update the maven version but in maven central it is the latest version updated in 2014 . Could you please help me how to overcome the above vulnerability(CVE-2014-9515 Dozer 5.5.1).

Please find the POM :

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
      <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I would recommend to replace that because since 2014 there is no update on Central... abandoned ... ?

Comment: Ah looks like they have moved https://github.com/DozerMapper/Dozer

Comment: can u pls help me with pom.xml dependency to import from git.

Comment: Is the vulnerability fixed in any of the versions?

Answer (score 0):

On the dozer webpage: https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer
you will find the snippet for your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.dozermapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>dozer-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But it will not fix the issue CVE-2014-9515.

The dozer project is currently not active and will more than likely be deprecated in the future. If you are looking to use Dozer on a greenfield project, we would discourage that. If you have been using Dozer for a while, we would suggest you start to think about migrating onto another library, such as:

[mapstruct](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct)
[modelmapper](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper)